# pyspark dataframe join all keys to collect_list() values

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark dataframe with a list of keys and values of the form:

```
    k1,v1
    k2,v2
    k3,v3
```

and I want to create:

```
    k1,[v1,v2,v3]
    k2,[v1,v2,v3]
    k3,[v1,v2,v3]
```

because I found out that k1=k2=k3.  I know this will involve collect_list() but I'm still not sure how to get the desired output.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
windowSpec = Window.orderBy("col1").rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)

from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df.withColumn("col2", F.collect_list("col2").over(windowSpec)).show(false)
```

Comment: Ramesh, why window is used here?

Comment: to denote whole dataframe as one window and also to update each rows with the aggragation function used. @RakeshKumar

Comment: you can achieve this by groupby("col1").agg(F.collect_list("col2")).show(), it will provide summerized resut that is  needed.

Comment: I don't think so. did you try it?

Comment: it will provide summerized resut that is needed, instead of updating all rows.

Comment: `groupby("col1").agg(F.collect_list("col2"))` is going to aggreate on grouped data. And k1, k2 and k3 all fall in different groups . so collect_list function will be applied on each groups. whereas OP is asking to collect_list on whole dataset as k1, k2 and k3 are equal. I hope you get my point. and please please try your solution. If it works then you post the answer too. I will upvote it. :)

Comment: yes k1,k2,k3 all have their own values and collect them. I think op mentioned that k1=k2=k3, i.e values for these 3 are same.

Comment: input is only sample data set instead of the complete data set.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, collect list will collect all values corresponding to `k1`, `k2` whether values can be repeated more than once.

Here is how we can do this:-
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

```
n = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
        ["k1", "v1"], 
        ["k1", "v2"], 
        ["k1", "v3"], 
        ["k1", "v1"], 
        ["k2", "v1"], 
        ["k2", "v2"], 
        ["k2", "v3"], 
        ["k2", "v1"], 
    ], ["col1", "col2"])
n.show()
+----+----+
|col1|col2|
+----+----+
|  k1|  v1|
|  k1|  v2|
|  k1|  v3|
|  k1|  v1|
|  k2|  v1|
|  k2|  v2|
|  k2|  v3|
|  k2|  v1|
+----+----+
n.groupby("col1").agg(F.collect_list("col2")).show()

+----+------------------+
|col1|collect_list(col2)|
+----+------------------+
|  k1|  [v1, v2, v3, v1]|
|  k2|  [v1, v2, v3, v1]|
+----+------------------+
```

If you need to remove duplicate:-

```
n.groupby("col1").agg(F.collect_set("col2")).show()
+----+-----------------+
|col1|collect_set(col2)|
+----+-----------------+
|  k1|     [v1, v2, v3]|
|  k2|     [v1, v2, v3]|
+----+-----------------+
```

Comment: look at your input dataframe and OP input dataframe. Are they same?

Comment: it's aggregated result of input, ie. needed in question. If you want to achieve  3rd column in input with collect_list values then you can join both input and output. If you need this also I can modify my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using @Rakesh dataframe `n`, you can create dataframe `m` by aggregating and collecting:

```
m = n.groupby("col1").agg(F.collect_set("col2").cast('string').alias('set'))

m.show()
```

Output:

```
+----+----------+
|col1|       set|
+----+----------+
|  k2|[v2,v3,v1]|
|  k1|[v2,v3,v1]|
+----+----------+
```

and concatenate them:

```
m.select(F.concat(m.col1, F.lit(','), m.set).alias('concatenated')).show()
```

Output:

```
+-------------+
| concatenated|
+-------------+
|k2,[v2,v3,v1]|
|k1,[v2,v3,v1]|
+-------------+
```